# How to compare between different date formats?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, datetime

I have four different date formats that I will store in a DB, Then show the latest ones.

The four different formats:

```
$a = '27. júní 2018 04:53';
$b = 'Friday, 09 March 2018';
$c = 'Fri, 29 Jun 2018 11:00:00 GMT';
$d = 'Mon, 18 Jun 2018 06:52:20 +0000';
```

They will be stored in a MYSQL Database.

What should I do with them?

Can SQL or MYSQL date type do the work?

Should I convert them using `strtotime()`?

Should I extract some data from specific ones to male them match?

Comment: *Can SQL or MYSQL date type do the work?* 
Maybe you should try before asking the question. Please post the code that you have tried and explain which part is not working.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Convert as you store into the table.

Comment: @RickJames, You mean before storing it or after?

Comment: Store a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` -- '2018-06-18 06:52:20`; no other form.

Comment: Yes, I tried the other formats, But MYSQL showed an error message.

That means that it should be converted with PHP first

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has three data types suitable for date/time values.  These are pretty well explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

You have three types of values:

- Date alone.
- Date with a time, but no time zone.
- Date with a time and a time zone.

But the basic questions to ask:

- Do you need just the date or is the time also necessary?
- Do you need the time zone?

If you need just the date, then `date` will do.  Otherwise, you want `datetime` or `timetamp`.  Which depends on how you want to treat timezones.

If you actually need to store the timezone with the value, then I would suggest that you think hard about whether this is really necessary.  Typically, `timestamp` is sufficient, because it stores values in UTC which can then be converted to any original timestamp.  You can store the original time zone in an alternative column.

If you really need to handle all three types with no compromise, then you might need to use a string.  In this case, you should use a correctly formatted string:

- YYYY-MM-DD
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS+TZ

The first two are readily converted to the appropriate type in MySQL.  For the third, you can extract the timezone and add it as an offset (with a bit of work).

However, I doubt whether this approach is necessary.  A `datetime` is probably sufficient.

Comment: I want to store them for two reasons,:

Comment: 1- Show each post creation date.

Comment: 2- Fetch the latest added posts from the DB.

Comment: Timezone is not important, I can extract it from the dates.

Comment: @Ashley . . . Then you should use either `timestamp` or `datetime`.  You can use `datetime` if the value is all from the same timezone, such as from the server time zone.

Comment: Does it work with other languages like the months names such as `$a = '27. júní 2018 04:53';`

Comment: @Ashley . . . Use ANSI/ISO standard formats --` '2018-06-27 04:53:00'`.

Comment: You mean converting it to that format before storing it in the Database?

Comment: What about the 3 other formats? should they also be converted to that format?

Comment: @Ashley . . .Yes, that is what I mean.  Store the data using the appropriate data type.  In your case, that would appear to be `datetime`.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have PHP knowledge to help me with a question ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134437/how-to-combine-the-data-for-the-same-post-together