# How to combine the data for the same post together?

Tags: php, arrays, rss, feed, simple-html-dom

I'm getting some posts data from 2 websites, One website has the title, the date, the description and the link, While the other has the title and the image.

So I want to add the image to the other posts data if the titles from both websites are identical.

Here is what I tried:

```
$articles = [];

//Getting Data From 1st Website
$rss = simplexml_load_file($website1);

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $post = []; 
    $post['title'] = (string)$item->title;
    $post['link'] = (string)$item->link;
    $post['date'] = (string)$item->pubDate;
    $post['description'] = (string)$item->description;

    $articles[$post['title']] = $post;
}

//Getting Data From The Second Website
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($website2);

    foreach($html->find($articlesClass) as $article) {
        $title    = trim($article->find($titlesClasse, 0)->plaintext);
        $img    = $article->find($imagesClass[$i], 0)->{'src'};     

        if ( isset ($articles[$title])){
            $articles[$title]['img'] = $img;
        }
        else    {
            $articles[$title] = ['title' => $title, 'img' => $img];
        }   
    }
```

How to add the other date (link, date and description) to the array with the title and image?

Comment: here you want to add 
        if ( isset ($articles[$title])){
            $articles[$title]['img'] = $img;
        }
        else    {
            $articles[$title] = ['title' => $title, 'img' => $img];
        }

Comment: I want to add the other data to that array, These data ` $post['link'] = (string)$item->link;
    $post['date'] = (string)$item->pubDate;
    $post['description'] = (string)$item->description;`

Comment: @mickmackusa, This problem is solved, I could delete it if you want, There is another related question if you could help with

Comment: I think deleting this one is the easy option.  If you have a detail-sensitive question, you can email.  Otherwise, you can post a new question.

Comment: You can also delete any comments on the other pages that are now meaningless.  Always try to keep this site tidy.

Comment: I have already asked the question, It's here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154846/how-to-remove-images-and-text-from-rss-feed-description-tag

Comment: I could send you these websites links that contain the description, If you need them

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
if (in_array($title, $articles)){
    $articles[$title]['img'] = $img;
} else {
     //
}
```

Comment: I want to add the other data not just the image

Comment: That code in the question adds the image, I need to add the other data

Comment: @Ashley Which data ?! from website1 ?