# How to remove images and text from RSS feed description tag?

Tags: php, regex, xml, rss, feed

I'm getting the description from some RSS feed websites, Some of these description contain images and specific text I want to remove.

The code to get the feed:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file($website);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $description = (string)$item->descritpion;
}
```

These are the different formats I get:

```
<description><![CDATA[
    <p> //Post Description </p>
    <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="">
        //Post Title.</a> appeared first on 
        <a rel="nofollow" href="">//Feed Website.</a>.
    </p>
]]></description>
_________________________________________________________________
<description><![CDATA[
    <div>
        <strong>//Some Text.</strong>
    </div>
    <div>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div>//Some Text.</div>
    <div>
        <img alt="" src="" style="width: 640px; height: 427px;" />
    </div>
]]></description>
_______________________________________________________________
<description>
    &lt;img style="margin:0 1em 1em 0;" align="left" src=""/&gt;
    „//Some Text. 
</description>
```

To remove images:

```
$description = (string)strip_tags($item->description);
```

The text is "The post (Post Title) appeared first on (Website)".

To remove that text I use:

```
if (strpos($description, 'appeared first')) {
    $siteNames = array('a.com', 'b.com', 'c.com');
    foreach ($siteNames as $siteName) {
        if(strpos($description, $siteName)){
            $appeared = 'The post '.$item->title.' appeared first on '.$siteName;
            $description = str_replace($appeared, '', $description);
        }

    }
}
```

So for example if the description contains:

```
 <p>The post 
    <a rel="nofollow" href="http://a.com/what-is-php">What is PHP.</a> 
    appeared first on 
    <a rel="nofollow" href="http://a.com">a.com.</a>.
</p>
```

Then that text should be removed.

Then I use `strip_tags($item->description)`, No images is shown.

But when I use the code to remove the string, It doesn't work with all the descriptions and some of them still have the string.

UPDATE:

```
<description><![CDATA[
    <p>Við vorum að fá inn til okkar forfallaholl í Laugardalsá á best tíma. Annarsvegar er um að ræða hollið 18-21. júlí og síðan hollið 24-27. júlí. Bæði eru hollin á frábærum tíma í ánn. Þó svo um 3ja daga holl sé að ræða, er að hægt að skoða staka daga eða 1 1/2 eða 2
    </p>
    <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="https://a.com/post-title/">Laugardalsá &#8211; forfallaholl á besta tíma</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="https://a.com">a.com</a>.</p>
]]></description>
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the data that **does** work, and a sample that **doesn't** work? Comparing the source data to each other would allow us to spot any differences that could cause your inconsistent results.

Comment: What is your expected output from above given XML?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh, The description tag inner text without images or the text "The post (Post Title) appeared first on (Site Name)"

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with regex? I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the post.

Comment: @emsimpson92, I didn't use it, But it could be used to replace that text, I'm seeking the possible solutions

Comment: @Ashley I want to help you, but this question is very Unclear for multiple users.  I'll be honest, even if I did answer this question for you (leveraging my prior knowledge of your Icelandic text), your question and my answer would be very unlikely to help anyone else in the future.  A good question is clear enough for _anyone_ to read, understand, and possibly answer.  Also, your sample input should very closely represent your actual data.  This data accuracy solves two future problems: 1. you avoid receiving a suboptimal solution 2. volunteers avoid follow up questions/debugging.

Comment: Specifically: a unicode flag is required for your regex pattern, but no one else could possibly know this based on this page alone.  You also need to copy/paste your code carefully.  When you post `$item->descritpion` but you actually have `$item->description` in your code, this will distract volunteers from solving your issue, because sharp-eyed coders will sniff out typos like this.

Comment: As you know, I will continue to help you, but first I must continue to "groom" you to become a "good poster".  We need to hone your question posting skills to avoid future troubles.  This benefits everyone.  Please take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour  then please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (you can follow the links at the bottom for more reading)  These steps are critical to successful interactions with this community.  This is not a waste of time.  You will get better, faster, clearer support when you follow these guidelines.

Comment: Try to make your questions SUPER easy to answer.  Provide ready-to-use variables (in this case an array of elements containing the 3 realistic `description` strings, then post your exact expected output from the input.  This way volunteers can test their code before providing their best version to you.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I shared a close examples as I could, I don't want to post the websites, If I provide the real examples these websites will be there

Comment: The code I shared is working with almost all of them, It just one website, For example if there are 10 posts, Only 2 or 3 are affected

Comment: You don't need to expose the urls.  Just "make up" some fake strings that contain _similar_ content.  Be sure to include Icelandic letters.  Provide snippets that are ready to use.

Comment: The question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/STReB))

```
$xml = '<![CDATA[
    <p>Við vorum að fá inn til okkar forfallaholl í Laugardalsá á best tíma. Annarsvegar er um að ræða hollið 18-21. júlí og síðan hollið 24-27. júlí. Bæði eru hollin á frábærum tíma í ánn. Þó svo um 3ja daga holl sé að ræða, er að hægt að skoða staka daga eða 1 1/2 eða 2
    </p>
    <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="https://a.com/post-title/">Laugardalsá &#8211; forfallaholl á besta tíma</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="https://a.com">a.com</a>.</p>
]]>';

$finds = [
    '~<p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="https?://[a-z]+\.com[^"]*">.*?</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="https?://[a-z]+\.com[^"]*">.*?</a>\.</p>~iu',
    '~^<!\[CDATA\[~',
    '~\]\]>$~'
];

var_export(trim(strip_tags(preg_replace($finds, '', $xml))));
```

Output:

```
'Við vorum að fá inn til okkar forfallaholl í Laugardalsá á best tíma. Annarsvegar er um að ræða hollið 18-21. júlí og síðan hollið 24-27. júlí. Bæði eru hollin á frábærum tíma í ánn. Þó svo um 3ja daga holl sé að ræða, er að hægt að skoða staka daga eða 1 1/2 eða 2'
```

I expect this should largely handle your data in the way that you require.  The first regex pattern is certainly the hairiest one (see the link for pattern explanation).  You will need to adjust the `[abc]\.com` to suit your needs --  potentially doing something like `(?:test\.com|example\.net|sample\.co\.uk)`.  Until you get it "just right" just feed some input data into regex101 and keep tweaking your pattern until it works.

The 2nd and 3rd patterns are just to clear away the text wrappers.  While the 2nd one is not truly necessary because `strip_tags()` will clean that substring away, the 3rd is critical because `strip_tags()` will leave a dangling `]]>`.

The first pattern is case-insensitive (`i`) and unicode-tolerant (`u`) for best results.

`^` and `$` are beginning and end of string delimiters.  If they are not suitable for your actual data, they can be removed.  These steps are just attempts to "mop up" any unwanted residual substrings.  The `trim()` call is certainly something that I would include so that the stored data is as clean as it can be.

If the specific `<p>` tagged substring to be removed is nested between two substrings to be kept, you may like to add another pattern to condense multiple `\s{2,}` to be a single space OR you might write `\s*` at the end of my first pattern to capture trailing whitespaces.  Only you will know this.